# Variable and text in $_POST[$]

Tags: php

What is the correct syntax to pass a text with a variable in it in $_POST ?

for example i have

`$i=1`
and want to use something like 
`$_POST[arrow_$i_1]`

Comment: How about to try? (Better approach: read the manual)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$_POST['arrow_' . $i . '_1']
```

Otherwise you can try with:

```
$_POST["arrow_${i}_1"]
```

Yoy have to use `{}` to let PHP know that everything after `}` is not a variable name.

Comment: For some reason this `$_POST[arrow_.$i._2]` seems to be working.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: You should NEVER use it without `""`. Lets say, someone will before declare: `define('arrow_', 'trolololo');` You will get: `trolololo_1_2`

Comment: Oh okay, changed it to metho 1. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Just put it in quotation marks, php automatically detects variables and replaces them with the value.

```
$_POST["arrow_${i}_1"];
```

Comment: that will have `$i_1` as the whole variable and not `$i`

Comment: Meeeh, youre fcking right. You need to use curly brackets in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it by :

```
$_POST["arrow_$i_1"];
```

or

```
$_POST['arrow_' . $i . '_1'];
```

Double quote sign (") makes you able to add variables inside the string.